# Wickets not picking up CSS

Tags: wicket

I am using the Wicket JQuery UI project from http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/. I have successfully created a sortable solution that allowed me to use the connectWith functionality from JQuery on more than 2 sortable lists. I wanted to expand upon this solution by using the JQuery placeholder option to show where the sortable would be dropped. I can see the placeholder option in the javascript that is generated but it appears the CSS class that I enter in the placeholder option is not correctly being applied.

I've gone so far as to add the CSS in the wicket:head tag but this still does not get picked up. However, if I debug the page in IE11 and manually add the style to the DOM Explorer Style tab the placeholder responds more or less how the JQuery examples work here, https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder.

This tells me that the option is working but the CSS is not being picked up. What am I missing?

Thanks

edit: First line is setting the jquery option in my class. The second line shows the placeholder option is the last option set in the Wicket javascript output. I've also added the CSS that the placeholder refers to as well as showing that the CSS is correctly being added to the Wicket app.

```
//sets the JQuery option. Used to also setup the connectWith and forcePlaceholderSize properties.
this.options.set( "placeholder", Options.asString( "itemPlaceholder" ) );

//Wicket Javascript output
jQuery('#crewOrder20').sortable({ "receive": function (event,ui) {var attrs = {"u":"./dashboard?0-1.IBehaviorListener.1-dashboardPanel-webMarkupContainer-crewSchedules-0-crewSchedule-box-boxBody-availability-0-crewOrder","c":"crewOrder20"};var params = [{"name":"hash","value":ui.item.data('hash')},{"name":"index","value":ui.item.index()}]; attrs.ep = params.concat(attrs.ep || []); Wicket.Ajax.ajax(attrs); } , "connectWith": "list of sortables", "forcePlaceholderSize": "true", "update": function (event,ui) { var attrs = {"u":"./dashboard?0-1.IBehaviorListener.0-dashboardPanel-webMarkupContainer-crewSchedules-0-crewSchedule-box-boxBody-availability-0-crewOrder","c":"crewOrder20"}; var params = [{"name":"hash","value":ui.item.data('hash')},{"name":"index","value":ui.item.index()}]; attrs.ep = params.concat(attrs.ep || []); Wicket.Ajax.ajax(attrs); } , "placeholder": "itemPlaceholder" });;

//CSS
.itemPlaceholder{ 
height: 1.5em; 
line-height: 1.2em; 
backaground: yellow;
```

}

```
private Styles() {
    super( Styles.class, "style.css" );
}

public static Styles getInstance() {
    return StylesHolder.INSTANCE;
}

private static class StylesHolder {
    public static final Styles INSTANCE = new Styles();
}

//setting the CSS class in the Wicket app
bundles.addCssBundle( App.class, "style-" + Version.Info.getVersion() + ".css",
            (CssResourceReference) PrettifyCssResourceReference.INSTANCE,
            Styles.getInstance() );
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pgadLzp/93/) showing the functionality as it should work.

edit: A further edit. I have confirmed that the CSS is being applied to other class properties I set through Wicket.

```
//this correctly applys the dispatch CSS to this label
label.add( AttributeModifier.append( "class", "dispatch" ) );
```

Comment: Please show us some code. It is hard to tell what is missing without any code.

Comment: Updated. Added a fiddle of how it should work as well.

Comment: Try to make the CSS rule more specific, e.g. `body div itemPlaceholder {....} `. Maybe jQuery UI css file is loaded after your CSS snippet and overrides it.

Comment: That was it. Something was either overwriting the class (not sure as I created the itemPlaceholder class) or I just needed to specify where exactly the class should be used. If you want to create an answer for this I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the CSS rule more specific, e.g. `body div .itemPlaceholder {....}`. jQuery UI css file is loaded after your CSS snippet and overrides it.